# Do native speakers use prepositions correctly all the time?

Tags: prepositions

I know, it's very weird questions. but just out of curiosity. I just want to know if they use prepositions correctly all the time.

as It is very hard for me to remember which prepositions to use, sometimes more than one prepositions come to my mind at the same time, and I don't understand which one to chose.

if you have got any tips for me which may help, please share them with me.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That sais, this is not an answerable question, and will probably be closed. You learn to speak English (or any other new language) ny readng, speaking, listening and learning some rules and how they work. You can ask here about any _particular_ usage question that  puzzles you, but not this general question about how native speakers use prepositiions.

Comment: Almost ***by definition***, any preposition use by a native speaker is "correct". Some are less common than others, is all.

Comment: I'll tell you one thing that *isn't* correct - "chose" in the present tense.  It's "choose" in the present tense and "chose" in the past - "today I choose, tomorrow I will choose, yesterday I chose".  Incidentally, I can say for sure that that one *is* a mistake I've seen a lot of native speakers make too!

Answer (score 3):

Native speakers learn language during childhood, and it has been recognized that the brain is especially receptive to language at this time.

Consider the complex grammar of Russian and German. Or Polish, they have seven cases: nominative (mianownik), genitive (dopełniacz), dative (celownik), accusative (biernik), instrumental (narzędnik), locative (miejscownik), and vocative (wołacz).

Do native speakers of Polish often use the wrong case. We can presume, almost never.

You automatically learn these complex grammar rules without instruction, just by listening and speaking at a very young age.

In English, the usage of prepositions is analogous to the Polish case system, in that a particular preposition applies to a given circumstance.

Isn't it the case in your own native language, that you yourself have no difficulty choosing the correct words, especially when it comes to simple words such as prepositions?

Comment: I am from India and I speak Hindi, in our country, people from different regions speak differently. even most often they say wrong prepositions but we can understand each other. isn't is the case in your country.

Comment: Not the same situation.  It may be that Hindi has various dialects which are similar enough to be mutually intelligible, yet still have significant differences.  That isn't really the case in the usa, canada, australia.    They have one major dialect, with only small regional accents and variations. In the UK, "Scots" could be considered a really different dialect.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that people agree on what the correct preposition is and that this remains unchanged over time. When I was growing up I was taught that I should always say *different from* and never *different to*. It was permissible under certain circumstances to say *different than*. Usage has changed over time and I hear careful adult speakers on national television and radio saying *different to* all the time. The good news is that listeners will nearly always understand you unless you have a really eccentric choice of preposition but if you are planning to take examinations that is no help to you and you just have to keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

Linguists would tell you that however native speakers talk **is** the correct way to speak that language.  If you don’t talk like the natives do, you won’t sound like a native.

Since you’re asking if people speak incorrectly, though, you presumably are speaking prescriptively, not descriptively. The question only makes sense if you have some set of rules for what constitutes “correct” English that many people don’t agree with.

That said, there are some supposed rules of formal written English that some people consider “correct,” but no one follows when speaking.  One is that some people consider it an error to end a sentence with a proposition.  Many of the same people consider it an error to “split an infinitive” by putting an adverb between *to* and the verb, as in “To boldly go.”  A rule that’s still followed is to write *should’ve,* *could’ve* and so on, not the homonym **should of*, which most people and all dictionaries consider an error.  There are also some people who look down on other dialects of English and consider their grammar to be inferior, even though neither linguists nor people from those communities would agree.

Prepositions, unfortunately, are not logical.  A good tip is to try searching [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams) for different ways to say the same thing, and see which ones are and are not used.  Prepositions are some of the trickiest bits of the language to learn.